# How to switch into AMD integrated graphics from Nividia external graphics on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, amd-processor

So I wish to switch to my integrated graphics, that is AMD since my processor is Ryzen 7 5800 and it comes with 2GB integrated one. I have an external Nividia RTX 3060 but it is causing issues and obviously consumes more power which is not needed on ubuntu.

The last time I tried to switch to a AMD GPU on a different system, it messed up my system a lot so I am hesitant in taking steps and asking the question here.

**Edit** My system is dual booted, so I am using windows and ubuntu both. Now windows have a feature where it switches between the GPUs according to the need of the system. But on ubuntu, I would like to stick to AMD integrated ones since it consumes less power there by increasing the hours I get from the battery.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to stop using the Nvidia card in all applications and OS s on the machine?

Comment: Well, I have dual booted the system. I would like to use it on windows but not ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the feature you’re looking for is prime-select (provided by the nvidia driver):

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Will disable the nvidia driver (after a logout):

```
nvidia-smi --loop=1
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

By default it should be on-demand:

```
sudo prime-select on-demand


nvidia-smi
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.86       Driver Version: 470.86       CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, and I could also do it by switching off the Nvidia drivers completely.